# How to make a ScollView with two swift files and one Objective C File in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I want to make a ScrollView with two screens and I make it with xib files. Two of them are swift files and one is a Objective C file. I create three Files which called View1, View2 and View3 (which is the Objective C file). Then I want to make the ScrollView with this code:

```
    let V1 : View1 = View1(nibName: "View1", bundle: nil)
    let V2 : View2 = View2(nibName: "View2", bundle: nil)
    let V3 : View3 = View3(nibName: "View3", bundle: nil)

    self.addChildViewController(V1)
    self.ScrollView.addSubview(V1.view)
    V1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    self.addChildViewController(V2)
    self.ScrollView.addSubview(V2.view)
    V2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    self.addChildViewController(V3)
    self.ScrollView.addSubview(V3.view)
    V3.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    var V2Frame : CGRect = V2.view.frame
    V2Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
    V2.view.frame = V2Frame

    var V3Frame : CGRect = V3.view.frame
    V3Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width * 2
    V3.view.frame = V3Frame

    self.ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * 3, self.view.frame.height)
```

But when I want to make V3 there is standing : "Use of undeclared type 'View3'". Is there a way to make it that it works and all there View Controllers where show in the ScrollView because it is very important that the two Swift files and the one Objective C file where show.

Thanks for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to say `#import "View3.h"` in the Swift bridging header, so that Swift can see the Objective-C class View3.